# How can I ensure a periodic task will run forever on a linux machine?

Tags: python, linux, distributed

I have a task that I want to periodically on a remote linux machine. What is the best way to ensure that it will run forever? I currently have it running as a celery job, but I wonder if a cron that simply calls a python script would be more durable.

My priorities are that if the task were to fail or exit with failure for some reason that the next scheduled job would run as normal.

Is there a better option than cron or celery? I know sometimes people use things like supervisor to ensure that a process restarts if it fails but what if supervisor fails?

Comment: What if init fails, what if the kernel fails, what if the hardware fails, what if the data center catches on fire?

Comment: Hint: *You almost answered your own question*; s/distributed/redundancy

Comment: Somewhere down the line you're probably going to have to have human intervention to catch a "what if". Personally for tasks like these, I have it running as a cron job, some kind of supervisor checking that the cron is running, and if it's not, start it. And additionally something that tells whoever's in charge of the cron running to be alerted if the cron hasn't reported in for X minutes. I rarely go _deeper_ than that. I could spend additional hours/days of my time devising more catch/fail-safe methods, but my existing system is effective 99% of the time at the moment, so is it worth it?

Comment: @MLeFevre- Can you expand on what you mean when you say you have some kind of supervisor checking if the cron is running and if it is not, start it.

Comment: @Sandman "Some kind of supervisor" today could be systemd, finit, supervisord or any other managed process supervision daemon.

Comment: @JamesMills:  I am actually not familiar with this method of process supervision. Would it be too much to ask for some good pointers for this stuff? I use cron jobs at the most. Does this layer(systemd, finit, supervisord) actually sit above the cron layer?

Comment: Yes generally; they "supervise" other processes. So you could for example run the cron daemon using supervisord

Comment: @Sandman typically in my cases a small bash script that checks all running processes for the one I'm monitoring, if it can find it, do nothing/sleep. If it can't find it, start it. You could go even further and have a system monitor in place like [watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog). You could go even further have a "cluster" system, where another machine automatically takes over if one goes down. But, the point I was trying to make to the OP was that you have to draw a line somewhere, and the "best quality for price" fail safe in the majority of cases is a human.

Comment: @JamesMills, MLeFevre: this opens up a whole vista of other options to build "durable, recurrent" processes. Well, of course, like you said MLeFevre, you can only build so much before you start over-engineering. I was not familiar with this layer and I fairly regularly need to run continuous data collection/mining routines.  Good to know! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MLeFevre Thanks for the information. In this case, the cost of restarting is pretty high, so having a few layers of protection will definitely be worth the up front investment. Really appreciate the info :)

Comment: Yeah no worries; sorry this *couldn't* really be answered per se; bit too broad :)

Comment: @eatCitrus If the *cost* of restarting or human intervention is quite high I really would design a bit of redundancy in your system with enough smarts. A cluster of sorts; if one fails the other picks up the slcak and they monitor each other.

Comment: To both the above points, yeah it is human intervention that would be required and that I am trying to avoid. And yeah, I knew in general that there are no silver bullets (oh this package is actual magic and runs forever) but was really looking for best practices in a situation where I'm ready to make significant investment in avoiding restarts. This has given me plenty to go on. Thanks again :)